# VS Debug Site is showing not available after stop debugging

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-3.0

We are currently developing a MVC 4 web application. Recently I may have changed some configuration in the "root/" web.config and "View/" web.config, since then every time I have to start debugging to access the website. I was able to just do build and visit my site.

I have tried to fix my config files but after hours of struggle I came to ask the question. I am not quite sure it is because of the changes in web.config

My VS is 2013.

Comment: Have you tried Debug-> Options -> Edit and Continue. Then uncheck Enable and and Continue

Comment: After I made changes as you have mentioned the issue has been solved. Please answer the question I will give you credit. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue a while back, I made the following change to fix it

Goto Debug-> Options -> Edit and Continue. Then uncheck Enable and and Continue

HTH